# Merging mysql data from two tables into one dataset and updating

Tags: mysql, union

I have two identical tables with different names which I would like to merge into one useable array dataset using some sort of query. I've heard the UNION function is good for this however I have never used it before.

OK so heres some pseudo table code:

TABLE_1 & TABLE_2

The query I would use to get data from both tables would be:

```
SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM TABLE_ WHERE ...

╔═════════╦═══════════╗
║ col_1   ║   col_2   ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║      37 ║         1 ║
║      37 ║         2 ║
║     ... ║       ... ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╝
```

How could I combine the data from both tables to get one dataset? I would also like to update records in the dataset but how could I do this if I don't know what table the data originated from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "merge into one dataset " is unclear... insert into a new table? Existing table? use in some way in an array?

Comment: I've updated it to say useable array dataset*

Comment: OK, then yes, the answer below will work.

Comment: Updated answer to include a column named "original_table" so you can key off of that if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use UNION:

```
(SELECT col_1, col_2, 'TABLE_1' AS original_table FROM TABLE_1 LIMIT 0,250)
UNION
(SELECT col_1, col_2, 'TABLE_2' AS original_table FROM TABLE_2 LIMIT 0,250)
```

Further info:

`UNION ALL` would also be an option which would give you duplicate identical rows (based on the data you supply, it seems you would not need this).

Updating of records would simply use `where col_1 = {value} and col_2 = {value2}`... doesn't matter which table was the originator.

edit: here it is working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71a88/1

Comment: If I wish to get 250 rows from the first table and 250 from the second would I use LIMIT 250 & LIMIT 500?

Comment: No, you would put `LIMIT 0,250` on each of the selects.

Comment: Like that?  answer updated with limits and paretheses

Comment: Yeah great, that works now thanks! With regards to updating do I just substitute SELECT for UPDATE and add the WHERE logic?

Comment: To update the original table? Well the [update syntax is different](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) but yes you would just `SET col_1 = {newValue} WHERE col_1={oldvalue} AND col_2={oldvalue2}`